# How to get post metas that doesn't exist with LIKE operator

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I want to get the posts where their specific post_meta doesn't exist. The problem is that one of its meta needs to use `LIKE` so I want to get sure that the `first_key` doesn't exist and the `second_key_%` which can include `second_key_1`, `second_key_2`, `second_key_3`, etc. doesn't exist too. However, the `compare` can't be both `NOT EXISTS` and `LIKE`.

Here is what I've done:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', function ($admin_query) {
  $custom_meta = array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
     'key' => 'first_key',
     'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
    ),
    array(
     'key' => 'second_key_%', // Issue is here
     'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
    )
  );

  $admin_query->set('meta_query', $custom_meta);
});
```

Comment: The WP_Query parameters aren't always suitable for all possible queries you might need, sometimes it is necessary to manipulate the generated SQL directly. Usually that is done using filters such as `posts_where` or `posts_join`. I am not sure what query exactly WP generates for a NOT EXISTS comparison, so I'd check what the generated SQL looks like first of all, and go from there.

Comment: Exactly! I wanted to get the raw query and add my own query to it but couldn't find that one either.

Comment: `WP_Query::request` should contain the full SQL statement. When you are manipulating the global query like the above filter does, then `$GLOBALS['wp_query']->request;` should give you access to it afterwards (like somewhere in your template.)

Comment: `WP_Query::request` returns `Undefined constant`. The `$GLOBALS['wp_query']->request` is null. I don't want to access it later but before querying the database. I want to add a filter at top of the posts list page in the dashboard. I have already added the button and I just need a query for posts that don't have those metas.

Comment: I know that you don't want to access it later, but as I said, I am not exactly sure what query WP creates based on those NOT EXISTS filters - so the first step would be to find _that_ out, and that means accessing the SQL _after_ this condition was added.

Comment: Are you manipulating the global query there, or is it some other "manually" executed query?

Comment: I just get the existing query which is showing all the posts on the post list page and want to modify it to filter the results.

Comment: Are we talking frontend, or admin backend? Just wondering, because the filter function parameter has been named `$admin_query`.

Comment: it is for the admin backend.

Comment: Try the Query Monitor plugin, https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/ - that lets you see all the database queries that have been performed.

Comment: It might show the queries performed but it doesn't show what variable should be modified to get the desired result.

Comment: As I keep saying, let's check what the current query (with the above filter applied) actually looks like, in SQL form - to _then_ try and figure out, which part of that needs changing ... what about that don't you get?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @CBroe, I could do it with `posts_where` filter.

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', function ($admin_query) {
  add_filter('posts_where', function ($where) {
    $where .= " AND wp_posts.ID NOT IN
    (
      SELECT wp_postmeta.post_id
      FROM wp_posts, wp_postmeta
      WHERE (wp_postmeta.meta_key LIKE 'second_key_%' OR wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'first_key') AND
      wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
    )";

    return $where;
  });
});
```